# Addition of matrices python

Tags: python, matrix, error-handling, syntax, syntax-error

I wrote a code to add given two matrices which is as follows:

```
A=[[2,3,4],[4,2,1]]
B=[[5,9,1],[2,4,2]]
R=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
for i in range(1):
    for j range(2):
        R[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j]
for r in R:
     print(r)
```

But whenever i run this code it gives this error:

```
for j range(2):
          ^
SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax
```

Any Idea why it says invalid Syntax

Comment: `for j in range(2)` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write “`in range`” there.